# Which one is correct "Designer is my dream job", "A Designer is my dream job", "Being a designer is my dream job"?

Tags: word-usage

An English teaching document, which is written by non-natives, says:

"**Designer is my dream job**"

[This page](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/article.htm) says that "**A singular countable noun can not stand alone**".

We can not say,

- "**I want to eat apple**"

But we can say:

- "**I want to eat an apple**"
- "**I want to eat apples**".

So, which one is correct:

- "**Designer is my dream job**"
- "**A Designer is my dream job**"
- "**Being a designer is my dream job**"?

Note: I found  "**Being a designer is my dream job**" a lot on Google.

Comment: I'd use the last one 'Being a designer is my dream job'. A slightly different alternative would be 'Designing [buildings / software / apparel] is my dream job'.

Answer (score 1):

Just like like you noted, and just like @Phylyp pointed out, the better way to say it is:

> "**Being a designer** is my dream job"

Answer (score 0):

**To be** a designer is my dream job.

Put another way: My dream job is **to be** a designer.

@Phylip's answer would apply if you already are working as a designer.